# Visual C++ generic template with class

Tags: generics, visual-c++

I am trying to declare a generic function that returns a struct (generically). I can only seem to find examples where people use primitive data types for this. What I have now is not throwing any visual studio errors until I try to compile, then I get LINK2019: unresolved external symbol.

**Below is my code:**

My header file (ShaderUtilities.h) has this definition:

```
class ShaderUtilities
{
public:
    ShaderUtilities();
    ~ShaderUtilities();
    template <typename T>
    static T* LoadShader(char*, ID3D11Device*);
};
```

And my class (ShaderUtilities.cpp) implementation has the following:

```
#include "ShaderUtilities.h"

ShaderUtilities::ShaderUtilities()
{}

ShaderUtilities::~ShaderUtilities()
{}

template <typename T>
static T* ShaderUtilities::LoadShader(char* shaderFileName, ID3D11Device* device)
{
    T* shader;

    //blah blah code here

    return shader;
}
```

All of the above compiles without issues; however, when I try to call it I get the above compiler error. This is how I am calling it:

```
ID3D11VertexShader* shader = ShaderUtilities::LoadShader<ID3D11VertexShader>((char*)"ColorVertexShader", m_Device);
```

Does anyone happen to know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!! Any advice is gladly welcomed!

Comment: The implementation of a template function must be in the header. The compiler needs to see it at the point of use.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks for replying. I added more code to my header/cpp file in the above question. Would you mind showing showing me an example of what you mean? Thanks again!!

Comment: What I mean is that the actual implementation, not just the declaration, of `ShaderUtilities::LoadShader` must be moved to `ShaderUtilities.h` from `ShaderUtilities.cpp`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ok, I will try that. Thank you so much for getting back to me, I really appreciate it!

Comment: That fixed it, thank you again!! Can you please add your comment as a reply so I can can credit you for answering it? Thanks!